# C# Stop BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, loops, backgroundworker

I have question about backgroundworker.

I have endless loop in backgroundworker. How can I stop it?

Comment: Please post the code of your worker so we can have a tad more insight as to what the problem is. (even if you remove code blocks and just show where you initialize the worker, what your worker is _vaguely_ doing, what you're doing to stop it currently).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change it to a non-endless loop.

The `BackgroundWorker` has built-in support for cancellation. To cancel a background worker call [`BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx). Also you need to modify the worker code to check for cancellation as mentioned in the documentation:

> CancelAsync submits a request to terminate the pending background operation and sets the CancellationPending property to true.
>
> When you call CancelAsync, your worker method has an opportunity to stop its execution and exit. The worker code should periodically check the CancellationPending property to see if it has been set to true.

So for example if you have this endless loop in your worker thread:

```
while (true)
{
    ...
}
```

then you could change it to:

```
while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
{
    ...
}
```

For cancellation to work you also need to set the property [`BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) to `true`. This can be done in the designer.